# Azure does not find any repositories in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've previously setup continuous deployment from VSTS to Azure. My previous sites are no longer working and I cannot setup new connections. When I try to setup continuous deployment from Azure portal I get this error:

```
Failed to set up continuous deployment
DESCRIPTIONFailed to set up continuous deployment for web app myproject, using Visual Studio Team Services. Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.InvalidOperationException: Vso GetRepository: Cannot find repository https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/myproject
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.<GetRepository>d__3f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext().
STATUSError
```

I've also tried to set it up from the old azure portal: [continuous integration using vso](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/). At step 4 "when authorization completes" I get an error saying that it cannot find any repositories.

I've tried setting up new repos, new websites, unlinking team services, old portal, new portal etc.

After unlinking team services and oauth-granting it again I get this error (almost the same but a bit different):

```
Failed to set up continuous deployment for web app myproject, using Visual Studio Team Services. Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Vso ListRepositories(SOMENUMBER@live.com): (401) Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.<ProcessResponse>d__83`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.<ListRepositories>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.<GetRepository>d__3f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the issue which Microsoft is investigating.

> Starting approximately at 21:30 UTC on 03 March 2016, engineers are
>   aware of an issue where a limited subset of customers may experience
>   errors when they try to setup Continuous Deployment in Web Apps with
>   Visual Studio Online Team Services via Classic Azure Management
>   Portal. (https://manage.windowsazure.com).
>
> Workaround: There are 2 workarounds currently available
>
> 1) Users can login in their Visual Studio Team Services' account and
>   use the new Azure Deployment build definition to setup continuous
>   deployment for Azure Web Apps
>
> 2) Alternatively, users on Git repositories can use the Azure Portal
>   (https://portal.azure.com/) to setup continuous deployment.

Refer to this link for details: [Investigating issues with Continuous Deployment from Classic Azure Management Portal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2016/03/05/investigating-issues-with-continuous-deployment-from-classic-azure-management-portal-3-5-investigating.aspx)

Comment: Except that this issue occurs on the Azure Portal as well. :(

Comment: Exactly, the second workaround does not work for VSTS (GIT repo). But maybe they are refering to bitbucket, github and others with "Git repositories". The first workaround isn't optimal for me either. I hope that they resolve this issue soon.